# How to Fix 'sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed' Error in PyCharm

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to learn Kivy Framework to develop a simple App to display a Label. I am using PyCharm IDE.

But when I click on Run, The following Error message occurs:

> [CRITICAL] [Text] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
>
> sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> pil - ImportError: No module named PIL

Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    return Label(text="This is a Label")

if __name__ == "__main__":
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You have to install PIL (aka pillow).

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm runs in its own virtual environment, so you need to install all the kivy dependecies in pycharm.
Depending on if you are on windows or linux, the dependecies for [windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html) and [linux](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html#common-dependencies) are listed on those pages.